# Ways to Handle Exceptions in vb.net Winforms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, exception, try-catch

I'm not sure if this is the place to post, but here goes.

I have an app (Windows Forms using VS 2012) that takes customer information through a series of forms and stores the info in SQL Server. The app will be deployed on computers on the local network (some remote but still on the same domain). I have validation at every step of user input. I'm not sure if it's naive to think this, but I feel like the only exception I have to worry about after thorough testing is at the connections to SQL Server (but I would love to hear where other things can go wrong). The way I see it, my app could throw exceptions when connecting to MSSQL (I have covered all the sql unique key errors, won't have anyone mucking with the columns, will have the necessary permissions, and require/restrict user input to what my columns require/permit), but I don't know how I would handle it - other than putting the code in a try/catch so that the user tries again - because if the connection fails, there's no point in skipping to the next line of code (or is this unreasonable as well). So my question is, what is the best (could be more than 1) way to do exception handling in this case? If I do have to wrap all of my connections in try/catch, is there a preferable way to log these, given that the app will be deployed locally (I'm concerned with saving them to the networked server in case the server is down temporarily). Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This has gone unanswered for some time, so I'll just update with what I've done.

Since the main error I anticipate is losing connection to SQL server, I embedded an XML document in my app and store everything in there after sending info to SQL server. When the customer finishes entering all information, if the server is still online, the XML data is purged. If not, the XML data remains and gets checked again on the next run. When connection is restored, the XML data is uploaded to SQL server and purged. This way, loss in connection shouldn't be noticeable.

I realize this doesn't really answer the question, but it is the best I can come up with at this point (until I learn more :)).